# Can the word "heel" be used in singular form in the phrase "on the heels of"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I read a sentence in The Hindu which was

This comes close on the heel of recent launch of Spotify in the country.

Can the word "heel" be used in singular form in the phrase "on the heels of"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British or American English, the idiom would not be modified in that way. I do not know if the idiom is different in Indian English; I know that there are a lot of differences, so it's plausible.

However, the idiom is *on the heels of*. Other idioms involving *heel* or *heels* exist, some singular and some plural, but that one is plural.

Answer (score 0):

*at (or on) the heels of* is an idiomatic expression meaning *following closely after*. I don't think it can (and should) be modified that way.